# Send an email to a email group using shell script

Tags: linux, email, shell, unix, solaris

Below is my shell script that is working fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_YEST_FORMAT2=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m%d",localtime(time()- 3600*96);'`
echo $DATE_YEST_FORMAT2

QUERY1=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT SUM(total_items_purchased), SUM(total_items_missingormismatch) from lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';`

QUERY2=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT 100 * SUM(total_items_missingormismatch*1.0) / SUM(total_items_purchased) FROM lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';"`

echo "Total items purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`"
echo "Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`"
echo "Error Percentage: $QUERY2"
```

I am running the above shell script like this below-

```
sh -x test.sh
```

**Problem Statement:-**

From the above shell script, I am getting below three things from the last three echo statements-

```
Total items purchased
Total Items MissingorMismatch
Error Percentage
```

I need to send all these above three things in an email to our email group we have `DL-host@company.com` by using that `shell script` above or suppose if I have `10 email list` to which I need to send email with the same contents and subjects, then I think, I can store all these 10 emails list in some variable and just read it from there and keep on sending, right?. Is this possible to do it? I was thinking email structure like this below, just making very simple.

**Subject**

Test Data

**Mail Body**

```
Total items purchased:-    Some Number
Total Items MissingorMismatch:-   Some Number
Error Percentage:-   Some Number
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

**Update, After trying larsks suggestions, I am getting only last echo statement in an email meaning only the error percentage one, not all three in a single email:-**

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_YEST_FORMAT2=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m%d",localtime(time()- 3600*96);'`
echo $DATE_YEST_FORMAT2

QUERY1=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT SUM(total_items_purchased), SUM(total_items_missingormismatch) from lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';`

QUERY2=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT 100 * SUM(total_items_missingormismatch*1.0) / SUM(total_items_purchased) FROM lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';"`

echo "Total items purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`"
echo "Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`"
echo "Error Percentage: $QUERY2" | mail -s "Test Data" rj@host.com
```

Comment: You missed the part where he used `{` and `}` to group the echo statements.

Comment: What's with running the first query twice only to extract different output fields?

Comment: @tripleee, what do you mean? I was not able to understand. Can you give some example what you saying?

Comment: Avoid the backticks altogether, run `hive ... query 1 text ... | awk '{ print "Total Items Purchased" $1; print "Total Items Missing or Mismatch:" $2 }'`. Overall, huge overuse of backticks for the sole purpose of `echo`ing the output; the `echo`s are inelegant and in some cases problematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically use the `/bin/mail` program to send email from a shell script.  You provide a subject and recipients on the command line and the message body on `stdin`.  For example, inside your script you could do something like this:

```
{
echo "Total items purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`"
echo "Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`"
echo "Error Percentage: $QUERY2"
} | mail -s "Test Data" DL-host@company.com
```

You can also pipe the output of an existing script into `mail` (if you don't want to modify the script, or if you only want to send mail somtimes):

```
<your script> | mail -s "Test Data" DL-host@company.com
```

You can specify multiple recipients on the command line, so:

```
... | mail -s "Test Data" address1@company.com address2@company.com
```

and so forth.

Comment: Thanks larsks for the suggestion, but it has confused me more. Can you provide me the exact code for all your cases, then I can understand more as I am new to shell script. So I am very confuse in understanding the syntax and all other things.

Comment: I updated the question with the script I tried as per your suggestion, but I got only last echo statement in an email.

Comment: The sample code is missing a closing '}' char before the '|' char. See my answers to http://stackoverflow.com/users/819916/nevzz03 . Are you guys working on the same project or is this schoolwork? (If so you should tag it as such.) Else, please coordinate your questions, rather than asking the same thing multiple times. Good luck.

Comment: You can also use `read v1 v2 <<< $QUERY1` instead of two separate `echo|awk` calls.

Comment: @glennjackman, I was not able to understand which part you are talking about?

Comment: `read v1 v2 <<< $QUERY1; { echo "Total items purchased: $v1"; echo "Total Items MissingorMismatch: $v2"; echo "Error Percentage: $QUERY2"; } | mail -s "Test Data" DL-host@company.com`