# Pipe the output from three echo statement to mail

Tags: linux, email, shell, unix, solaris

```
echo "Total items: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`"
echo "Total Error: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`"
echo "Percentage: $QUERY2"
```

How can I send these three things in a single email using `mail command`. So the mail body should be like this below whenever I get any email, in each line there should be one echo statement-

```
Total items:-    Some Number
Total Error:-   Some Number
Percentage:-   Some Number
```

I am running `SunOS`

```
bash-3.00$ uname -a 
SunOS lvsaishdc3in0001 5.10 Generic_142901-02 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Comment: Can you not pipe it to a tmp file and just pipe that?

Comment: all these echo statements are there in my shell script and from that shell script only I need to pass these three echo statements in a single email.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send an email to a email group using shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875036/send-an-email-to-a-email-group-using-shell-script)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your requirement is not completely clear, but try this

```
{
    echo "Total items: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`"
    echo "Total Error: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`"
    echo "Percentage: $QUERY2"
} | mail -s "subject" toUser1@xyz.com,toUser2@abc.com
```

The `{ .. }` pair creates a process group, and all std-output is redirected into the 1 `|` (pipe), which connects to the std-in of your mail program.

You may need to use `mailx`, `-s` specifies subject, which I see from your other question on this topic that you seem to understand.

Also `sendmail` will need to be running and properly configured for any mail to be delivered from the machine that you execute this script.

IHTH

---

**Edit: 2015-11-07**

Just got a 'nice answer' star for this, and on on review, I'm surprised that I didn't comment on excessive use of processes. For this case, this can be reduced to one call to `awk`, i.e.

```
awk -v q1="$QUERY1" -v q2="$QUERY2" \
 'END {
    split(q1,q1arr)
    print "Total items: " q1arr[1] \
          "Total Error: " q1arr[2] \
          "Percentage: " q2
}' /dev/null \
| mail -s "subject" toUser1@xyz.com,toUser2@abc.com
```

Or for the one-liner crowd ;-), that is

```
awk -v q1="$QUERY1" -v q2="$QUERY2" 'END {split(q1,q1arr);print "Total items: " q1arr[1] "\nTotal Error: " q1arr[2] "\nPercentage: " q2 }' /dev/null | mail -s "subject" toUser1@xyz.com,toUser2@abc.com
```

The `{ .. }` aren't needed in this case, as there is only one process connecting to the pipe.

For a case like a summary report being sent once a day, the original code is completely usable (but non-optimal). However, coding non-optimally leads to bad habits. Calling 5 processes when one will suffice in a loop that runs 1000s of times in a day, will consume compute resources unnecessarily.

Finally, as the o.p. didn't include any sample data, the code is only lightly tested.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a function in bash and | (pipe) it to sendmail.

```
            #!/bin/bash

            echo_statement(){

            echo "Total items: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`"
            echo "Total Error: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`"
            echo "Percentage: $QUERY2"

            }
            echo_statement | mail -s "subject" you@yourdomain.com
```