# Send email after Snakemake workflow finishes successfully on SLURM

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, email, snakemake

Is there way to send an email after a `Snakemake` workflow finished when using the `--slurm` option?
Something like this:

```
onsuccess: 
    email(example@hello.com, title="Snakemake job xxx finished successfully")

onerror:
    email(example@hello.com, title="Snakemake job xxx failed")
```

SLURM scripts have this option:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --mail-type=END,FAIL
```

I would not like an email after each rule has finished though, but after the whole workflow has finished.

Comment: You could pipe the output like "snakemake somerules | mail -s example@hello.com" like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875689/pipe-the-output-from-three-echo-statement-to-mail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using snakemake's `shell` function. Here's what the rule would look like:

```py
EMAIL = "me@mi.mo"

onsuccess:
   shell("mail -s 'DONE' {EMAIL} < {log}")

onerror:
   shell("mail -s 'ERROR' {EMAIL} < {log}")
```

Note that `{log}` is also built-in for snakemake, so it will attach the log contents as the body of the email.